# Cakephp Multiple Forms 1 Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cakephp, form-submit

I want to create 2 forms in a view. Only 1 form is visible.
The another one is hidden.

Hence, I want to have only 1 submit button for both form.

Code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Payment', array('type' => 'post', 'url' => 'https://uat.pbbank.com/payment/dpayment.jsp')); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('merchant_id', array('value'=>'3242', 'name'=>'merchant_id', 'id'=>'merchant_id')); 
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Payment'); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('merchant_id', array('value'=>'3242', 'name'=>'merchant_id', 'id'=>'merchant_id')); 
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Comment: can you share your code ? what have you tried?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. I would suggest having a submit button per form and using javascript to submit both forms on click.

Comment: For most situations just having hidden input fields in a single form will suffice, post your code and give some insight into the purpose of the dual forms.

Comment: @Zeeshan I already update the question. I want 2 form, will insert almost same data, but go to different action. 1st action will save the data to my database. 2nd will bring the data to payment gateway.

Comment: @DavidYell yes yes. i can use that method also. you have any example for that?

Comment: @danielsmile i cant put it in same form because I want to submit it to different action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be with Ajax, or JS/Jquery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $.post($("#addToDB").attr("action"), $("#addToDB").serialize(),
              function () {
                  alert('Add to Database submitted');
              });

            $.post($("#paymentGateway").attr("action"), $("#addToDB").serialize(),
              function () {
                  alert('Payment Gateway submitted');
              });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The form:

```
<form id="addToDB" action="addtodatabase.php" method="post">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<!-- Hidden form for payment gateway -->
<form id="paymentGateway" action="paymentgateway.php" method="post">
    <!-- Payment gateway input fields -->
</form>
```

Clicking the button with `id="submit"` calls function to post both forms by form id.

Answer (score 0):

you better wrap your form data and send your request with ajax to (https://uat.pbbank.com/payment/dpayment.jsp) and your action normal click event.

Comment: hi what did you mean by wrap the form? sorry i still new. hee