# Cakephp Send Multiple Form at once didnt work on mozilla

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp, form-submit, mozilla

I have two forms in a page. And I need the form to be submit on single click.

i use below code:

form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Payment', array('id' => 'addToDB', 'type' => 'post')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('merID'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('card_number', array('label'=>false, 'min'=>16, 'type'=>'select')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name_on_card', array('label'=>false, 'type'=>'select')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('security_code', array('label'=>false, 'type'=>'select')); ?>
<?php $options = array
    (
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'id' => 'submit',
    'div' => array(
    'class' => 'glass-pill',
    )
); 
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end($options); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Payment', array('id' => 'paymentGateway', 'type' => 'post', 'url' => 'https://uat.pbbank.com/payment/dpayment.jsp')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('merID'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('card_number', array('label'=>false, 'min'=>16, 'type'=>'select')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name_on_card', array('label'=>false, 'type'=>'select')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('security_code', array('label'=>false, 'type'=>'select')); ?>
<?php $options = array
    (
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'id' => 'submit2',
    'div' => array(
    'class' => 'glass-pill',
    )
); 
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end($options); ?>
```

javascrip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit2").click(function () {
            $.post($("#addToDB").attr("action"), $("#addToDB").serialize(),
              function () {
                  alert('Add to Database submitted');
              });

            $.post($("#paymentGateway").attr("action"), $("#addToDB").serialize(),
              function () {
                  alert('Payment Gateway submitted');
              });
        });
    });
```

it's work fine on chrome, but not mozilla.
Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you use `$("#addToDB").serialize()` in second `$.post` instead of `$("#paymentGateway").serialize()`. Could you provide forms HTML and errors you get?

Comment: @Zudwa i already update my question. I didnt get any error. seems like only 1 form was submitted.

Comment: You are trying to make ajax request to another domain. This is restricted due to security reasons. You can use a JSONP request in order to make it work. Note that you can only make GET request, not POST. And don't forget to prevent default event on click in `.click()`, otherwise in addition to ajax calls your forms are submitted normally. You can read about making JSONP request here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example).

Comment: @Zudwa hi, i try to understand what you explain. But i didnt get it. I've never use JSONP before. can you please give me the example.

Comment: Is uat.pbbank.com your domain? I mean, are you developing it's backend?

Comment: @Zudwa nope. that is for the payment. i want to save the data to my database, and also to sent the data to that url.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50854/discussion-between-zudwa-and-dancingangel)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cakephp Multiple Forms 1 Submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078573/cakephp-multiple-forms-1-submit-button)

Comment: nope. it's different question. @IsaacRajaei that is my question. and i already got the answer there. but the code is working fine on IE, chrome, opera. but not mozilla. thats y im asking now HERE

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very poor.

1. **you just need one form**
2. You will need to wrap(serialize) your form[paymentGateway] and
3. send the request to Payment Gateway
4. then when you get the result OK
5. save your data into Database

   ```
   $("#submit2").click(function () {
      //wrap your form once
      $data = $("#addToDB").serialize();

       $.post($("#paymentGateway").attr("action"), $data,
         function (firstresult) {
             //if Payment Gateway result is correct 
             if (firstresult==OK){
                  //then save it into Database
                  $.post($("#addToDB").attr("action"), $data,
                  function (secondresult) {
                         if (secondresult) {
                               alert('Payment Successful');
                         }
                   });
             }
         });
   });
   ```